# What to do when a bug is asked about, but is discovered to be based on a lower-level bug?

Tags: support

I have the following question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475107/jsignature-ie11-touch-not-working

I think I discovered a lower level bug that is the reason for this issue. Should I:

- Close this question and ask a new question?
- Edit this question to basically replace this one with the new one?
- Leave this question and open a new one for the lower level bug? Once a solution is found to the low level bug, then I can post an answer to the higher level bug to catch those with similar issues coming from Google searches.

Answer (score 4):

If you have discovered additional information while attempting to answer your question that helps give some insight as to what is going on, but that does not actually answer the question, then simply edit the question to include the addition information you have discovered.  While a few things may change, I would *expect* this to be a primarily additive process, not "replacing the whole question".

Comment: I was thinking about that but also wondering about how that would fit into the catching other users who might not be searching for this bug specifically through `jSignature`

Comment: Hm?  Google searchers will find the question based on it's *current* form, whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Servy, I'd agree that you should edit and add the info about the lower level bug to the original question. It is sometimes the case that even though the lower-level bug is hard to fix/workaround, there can sometimes be an easier workaround for the higher level issue (e.g. not using the library or using alternate methods that doesn't suffer from the same issue). An answerer can then chose to address the higher level issue if they deemed it appropriate.